# How to insert text, at cursor position, within existing text in a textbox using Command buttons?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a custom calculator whose buttons when pressed, insert their caption into a textbox.

```vb
Private Sub CmdBtn_Click()
    Me.TextBox.Value = Me.TextBox.Value & " " & CmdBtn.Caption
End Sub
```

With this method one cannot insert text in a text that exists.

For example, if current text is "abc" then I want to input "x" between "a" and "bc" to give me end result of "axbc".

I will put my cursor at the position where new text should be placed.

Comment: How would vba know where to input the new string within the existing one?

Comment: I will input the cursor using mouse. Then the new caption should be inserted on my cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Store the cursor position using a variable when leaving the textbox:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private LastPosition    As Long

Private Sub CmdBtn_Click()

    Dim Text    As String

    Text = Me!TargetBox.Value

    ' Insert source text at the stored position.
    Me!TargetBox.Value = Left(Text, LastPosition) & Me!SourceBox.Value & Mid(Text, LastPosition + 1)

End Sub

Private Sub UserName_LostFocus()

    ' Store cursor position.
    LastPosition = Me!UserName.SelStart

End Sub
```

Comment: I think `Selstart` keeps its value even after the edit box lost foucs - so no need to keep it in a global var.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, it works for inserting values on cursor point. But now, even if I type a new text, it also starts from left and every new word gets typed on the left end in the form "CBA" whereas, by default it should have been "ABC" if I type A, B and C in order.

Comment: Actually, it does not work without declaring LastPosition variable in MS Access 2016. I found the solution to my problem. Let me post here.

Comment: Don't know what you do. The solution posted is tested and works here.

Comment: Yes, that might be working for editing records only when a cursor is placed. However, when I add a new record without clicking anywhere, in that case, I had to adjust your code a bit to avoid issues.

Comment: OK, but not easy to guess, as you wrote: _I will input the cursor using mouse. Then the new caption should be inserted on my cursor position._

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works perfectly for inputting text at any position of TextBox. Let me know if someone has a better solution than this.

```
Private LastPosition as Long
Private Text as String

Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus()
        If LastPosition = 0 and IsNull(Me!TextBox.Value) Then
              Me!TextBox = " " + Me.ActiveControl.Caption
              LastPosition = LastPosition + Len(Me.ActiveControl.Caption)
        ElseIf 
              LastPosition >= AND Not IsNull(Me!TextBox.Value) Then
              Text = Me!TextBox.Value

              Me!TextBox.Value = Left( Text, LastPosition) & " " & _
              Me.ActiveControl.Caption & Mid(Text, LastPosition + 1)

              LastPosition = LastPosition + Len(Me.ActiveControl.Caption)

        Else  
              Me!TextBox.Value = Me!TextBox.Value + " " + Me.ActiveControl.Caption

        End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, Access doesn't store SelStart if the form is in edit mode. No idea why. Perhaps this is why the OP and the first answer got different results, though.

Anyway, this fix will solve that issue.

```
Private LastPosition    As Long

Private Sub UserName_Change()
    ' Store cursor position in edit mode
    LastPosition = Me!UserName.SelStart
End Sub

Private Sub UserName_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) 
    ' stores cursor position on non-change typing, like arrow keys
    LastPosition = Me!UserName.SelStart
End Sub

Private Sub UserName_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single) 
    ' stores cursor position when user clicks in a new spot
    LastPosition = Me!UserName.SelStart
End Sub

Private Sub UserName_LostFocus()
    ' Store cursor position, but only if not in edit mode
    If Not Me.Dirty Then LastPosition = Me!UserName.SelStart
End Sub
```